# cordova-hot-code-push not working

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I've installed the plugin **cordova plugin add cordova-hot-code-push-plugin** and have started the server **cordova-hcp server** in the app directory

In the config.xml I've specified the below configurations

```
<chcp>
    <config-file url="https://498b62ba.ngrok.io/chcp.json"/>
    <auto-download enabled="true" />
    <auto-install enabled="true" />
</chcp>
```

When I change any file in the www folder, I get a log in the cordova-hcp server console

```
Build 2016.07.02-16.10.16 created in /Users/my.name/Documents/Cordova_Workspace/MyProject/www
Should trigger reload for build: 2016.07.02-16.10.16
```

When I launch, or re-launch the app (on real Android phone), I get a logs the android console

```
07-02 15:45:22.499 7795-7869/? D/CHCP: Starting loader worker 
07-02 15:45:22.501 7795-7869/? D/CHCP: Failed to update
07-02 15:45:22.501 7795-7869/? D/CHCP: Can't load application config from installation folder. Reinstalling external folder
07-02 15:45:22.502 7795-7869/? D/CHCP: Current release is corrupted, reinstalling www folder from assets
07-02 15:45:22.502 7795-7869/? D/CHCP: Dispatching before assets installed event
```

Due to this no changes are reflected in the app. Need help over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved. Looking at forums, below are the correct steps

1. Run `cordova plugin add cordova-hot-code-push-plugin` in the project
2. Install `npm install -g cordova-hot-code-push-cli` on the system
3. Run `cordova-hcp init` and enter details
4. Run `cordova-hcp build`
5. Add the following in config.xml

   `<chcp>
       <config-file url="https://example.com/chcp.json"/>
   </chcp>`
6. Run `cordova build`